# Connecting scaffolds and changing forms - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am fairly new to RoR so sorry for this question:

I have several scaffolds which I have created: Universities, Events, Companies. The relationships are as follows:

Here are the models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :university
belongs_to :company
end

class University < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :events
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :events
end
```

I am trying to make a dropdown in my new event form which provides options for university and for company. At the moment all of these models have ids but in the form for new event, I have only "string" for company and for university (i.e. not linked in the form, no dropdown). Can someone help on what I should have in this form?

Here is the form code:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field form-group">
     <label><%= f.label :company, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %></label>
  <div class="col sm-6">
    <%= f.text_field :company, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <label><%= f.label :university, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>        </label>
  <div class="col sm-6">
        <%= f.text_field :university, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <label><%= f.label :name, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %></label>
  <div class="col sm-6">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is fairly simple you will have to use like below example.

```
<%= f.collection_select :university_id, University.all, :id, :name %>
<%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name %>
```

You should look at these gems https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form , https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic they make life much easier.

Let me know if you have any other problems.

Comment: Thanks very much - the problem is that I am now getting an "undefined error" message when I try to create a new event:   undefined method `company_id' for #<Event:0x8276040>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/events/new.html.erb

Comment: Maybe I need to use the controller in some way? Thanks!

Comment: Can you send me the Event model ?

Comment: Sure - it's just class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
belongs_to :university
belongs_to :company
end